# Mobile App not in Line with Desktop Website

Tags: discussion, support, bug, tags, mobile-web

I was using my mobile to access Stack via the app. I ended up going over to my profile and looked at my top tags.

It stated that I had 79 under `.htaccess`: (sorry for size of screen shot).

> [image: Phone Screen shot]

I then returned to my computer later and looked on my profile again, however this time it stated that my `.htaccess` under top tags was 77:

[image: top tags pc]

Not a major issue, but one I found interesting enough to mention. Any ideas why this might be happening? As you can see, it is not the only tag this is happening with.

Comment: Did you rule out caching?

Comment: @rene I've cleared my cache to test that. Still the same issue.

Comment: It is not your cache, but the server-side cache ....

Comment: Both has since updated, still the same difference.. strange..

Comment: I've learned overtime to not be bothered too much by differences in numbers that rely on scripts to run. If the explanation isn't caching, it is an unicorn that slipped, hardly ever a confirmed bug is found and fixed.